# Trying to get started with pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm following the guidance to set up pages and am having no luck:

1. [I set it to use the master branch and use the docs folder.](https://github.com/DavidThielen/LouisHowe/settings/pages) I clicked Save and - the docs folder was not created.
2. [It discusses how to add a Jekyll theme](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll) - but there is no _config.yml file. Where can I find that file?
3. What will the url be to the root page?
4. Is there a good getting started guide? [I found this](https://harrywang.medium.com/how-to-host-static-markdown-web-pages-using-github-pages-61f80a3a5136) but it does not show how to set it up.
5. How do I get the default README.md?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, GitHub Pages must be enabled for your repository in "Settings > Pages". Then you can manually add the `_config.yml` file in GitHub with "Add file > Create new file". Then the installation information for the Cayman theme is in their GitHub [repo](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman). Add the necessary lines to the file, save and commit your changes, and it should work. Make sure that, on the bottom-right of the main page, "github-pages" is listed as a Deployment

Comment: I'm responding gently because you are a new user and I appreciate your trying. But key to answering in SO is understand the parameters of a question and answer within those constraints. (With the exception of course that if the parameters are impossible, say so.) This is for an existing repo and therefore changing the name would be a giant PITA. In addition, the GitHub documentation does not anywhere say there's a naming restriction for using pages. Your answer, I believe, is more for the approach where a repo is the website.

Comment: I realise my previous answer was erroneous. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Much better. And it partially answers as it tells me that GitHub does not create that file (even though their documentation leads one to believe it does). thanks

Comment: Very good  If you add the lines from the Cayman [repo](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman) and wait a little while, the theme should be visible. And, by the way, GitHub removed the theme switcher quite recently. I'm glad I was able to help.